# Why am I getting Cannot read property 'INTERNAL' of undefined and Cannot instantiate firebase-analytics.js - be sure to load firebase-app.js first

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am having some weird errors in the console with my React app using Firebase. I'm trying to get it to work, I have read other questions, and nothing seems to be working for me here.

Thank you

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
// import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
// import firebase-app from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/analytics';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyAMwjhURlGsKdG7dmzhj3xT7g43uYEtaK4',
    authDomain: 'rick-gove-portfolio.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://rick-gove-portfolio.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'rick-gove-portfolio',
    storageBucket: 'rick-gove-portfolio.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '754254251822',
    appId: '1:754254251822:web:5b65400233755204e29cbf',
    measurementId: 'G-6RFVLXCVFG',
});

export const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
// firebase.analytics();
```

my errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'INTERNAL' of undefined
    at index.ts:41
    at index.ts:79
    at firebase-analytics.js:1
    at firebase-analytics.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.ts:79
(anonymous) @ firebase-analytics.js:1
(anonymous) @ firebase-analytics.js:1


index.ts:79 Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate firebase-analytics.js - be sure to load firebase-app.js first.
    at index.ts:79
    at firebase-analytics.js:1
    at firebase-analytics.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.ts:79
(anonymous) @ firebase-analytics.js:1
(anonymous) @ firebase-analytics.js:1
```